# Azure Data Factory Backup

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I have developed a sample project in Azure. My Azure Data Factory Trail version with free credits is about to expire. Could you please tell me how to backup everything? Thanks

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answers below resolved your question, If yes, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can click `Set up code repository` button, then you can save all your resource to Azure DevOps or Github.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

one way is to save the code in code repository as rightly mentioned by @stevezhao.
Other way is to extract the ARM template :

[image]

And you can import it into any new ADF

Answer (score 0):

In azure data factory you can integrate DevOps repo. or GitHub repo. Where you can push your code and can use the same repo. in other subscription.